# Realizar consulta que por medio de un campo muestre toda la informacion de un usuario

Tags: java, sql, validación, framework

Este proyecto se esta trabajando con DAO

Hice la siguiente consulta la cual sigo validando , lo que intento hacer es como puedo leer la informacion del usuario que por medio de un solo campo me muestre o me enlace toda la informacion de ese usuario en demas campos , puede ser filtrando o por nombre de proveedor y que me traiaga toda la informacion o por identificacion de proveedor y que me traiga toda la informacion, para este query tengo una validacion que ejerce el siguiente  metodo que hace el llamado a la query:

**Consulta**

```
query.propertiesM

getProveedoresByEmpresaRecepcion=SELECT P.* FROM RECEPCION_SELECT.EMPRESA_RECEPCION_PROVEEDOR AS EP INNER JOIN RECEPCION_SELECT.PROVEEDOR AS P ON EP.IDENTIFICACION_PROVEEDOR = P.IDENTIFICACION_PROVEEDOR WHERE EP.IDENTIFICACION_PROVEEDOR  = '20202020'
```

Aquie hago el llamado a la consulta

```
ProveedorDAO.java

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Proveedor> findAllByEmpresaRecepcion(final BigInteger identificacionEmpresaRecepcion) {
        getEntityManager().getEntityManagerFactory().getCache().evictAll();
        getEntityManager().clear();
        getEntityManager().joinTransaction();
        final String sqlString = MessageReader.getString(getQueries(), "getProveedoresByEmpresaRecepcion", Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
        final Query query = getEntityManager().createNativeQuery(sqlString, Proveedor.class);
        query.setParameter(1, identificacionEmpresaRecepcion);
        
        return (List<Proveedor>) query.getResultList();
    }
```

```
EJBconfiguracionRecepcionM.java

@Override
    public List<ProveedorDTO> getProveedores(final BigInteger identificacionEmpresaRecepcion) {
        return ProveedorMapper.MAPPER.toTarget(proveedorDao.findAllByEmpresaRecepcion(identificacionEmpresaRecepcion));
    }

    @Override
    public ProveedorDTO getProveedor(final String identificacionProveedor) {
        return ProveedorMapper.MAPPER.toTarget(proveedorDao.findById(identificacionProveedor));
    }
```

Aqui hago la validacion y no se si deba cambiar algo, depronto hacer una condicion aqui mismo esta validacion de codigo, pero sigo pensando como , para que el comportamiento que busco que haga, sea de que consulte en el Front la informacion del usuario ya sea por nombre o identificacion cualquiera de esos dos campos me muestre toda la informacion.

```
Proveedorview.java

public void visualizarProveedor () {
        this.proveedores = new ArrayList<ProveedorDTO>();
        this.proveedoresBK = new ArrayList<ProveedorDTO>();
        try {
            if (proveedores.isEmpty()) {
                LOOGER.info(idEmpresaRecepcion + "");
                proveedores = ejbConfiguracionRecepcionRemote.getProveedores(idProveedor);
                proveedoresBK.addAll(proveedores);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("visualizarProveedor", e);
            addMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

este es html

```
Proveedor.xtml

<ui:define name="head">
    </ui:define>

    <ui:define name="content">
        <h:form id="formVerProveedor">
            <h:panelGroup id="display_filter" rendered="#{ProveedorView.display_filter}">
                <div class="card">
                    <h1>Lista de Proveedores</h1>
                    <div class="ui-g ui-fluid">
                        <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-4">
                            <h:outputLabel for="idProveedor"
                                value="Identificación Proveedor" styleClass="aboveLabel">
                            </h:outputLabel>
                            <p:inputText id="idProveedor" required="false"
                                value="#{ProveedorView.idProveedor}">
                            </p:inputText>
                            <p:message for="idProveedor" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-4">
                            <h:outputLabel for="nombreProveedor"
                                value="Nombre Proveedor" styleClass="aboveLabel">
                            </h:outputLabel>
                            <p:inputText id="nombreProveedor" required="false" maxlength="100"
                                value="#{ProveedorView.nombre}">
                            </p:inputText>
                            <p:message for="nombreProveedor" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="ui-g-6 ui-md-3">
                            <p:commandButton value="Consultar"
                            update=":formVerProveedorTabla:tablaProveedor, :messages:growl"
                            action="#{ProveedorView.buscarEmpresaProveedor()}"></p:commandButton>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ui-g ui-fluid">
                    <div class="ui-g-6 ui-md-3">
                        <p:commandButton value="Crear" update=":formVerProveedor, :formCrearProveedor, :formVerProveedorTabla"
                        action="#{ProveedorView.vistaCrear()}" immediate="true"></p:commandButton>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </h:panelGroup>
        </h:form>
```

Esta es la vista el cual si filtro la busqueda por dos campos me sale toda la informacion del usuario, ahora si no coloco nada me busca toda la informacion de los usuarios, pero en este caso lo que deseo hacer es que solamente con un solo campo puede ser identificacion o nombre me muestre toda la informacion del usuario y es ahi donde tengo la duda.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: porfavor solicito una orientacion para esto

Comment: puedes poner el codigo completo relevante de ProveedorView? esto para tener un [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

repondiendo su inquietud, debe usar un "or", por ejemplo:

```
WHERE EP.IDENTIFICACION_PROVEEDOR  = '20202020'or EP.NOMBRE like %juan%
```

Pero tenga en cuenta que un dato como el nombre debe ser usado como identificador de un registro porque resulta ambiguo